# Cannot read property 'TUT' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, undefined

I loaded a json file with jquery and then tried to access certain properties but I get an undefined error. When I print the json object, I can clearly see the object in it.

```
{
 "Calculus 1": {
    "LEC": {
      "sections": [
        "LEC01",
        "LEC02"
      ],
      "days": [
        [
          "MO",
          "WE"
        ],
        [
          "MO",
          "TH"
        ]
      ],
      "start": [
        [
          "12:00",
          "11:00"
        ],
        [
          "13:00",
          "13:00"
        ]
      ],
      "end": [
        [
          "13:00",
          "13:00"
        ],
        [
          "14:00",
          "15:00"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "TUT": {
      "sections": [],
      "days": [],
      "start": [],
      "end": []
    },
    "PRA": {
      "sections": [],
      "days": [],
      "start": [],
      "end": []
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how a simplified version of my JSON looks like. The part in my code that tries to access a property looks like this.

```
if(info[courses[i]]['TUT']['sections'].length == 0){
         tut = -1;
}
```

Here is how I loaded my JSON. The code above is inside the some function. When I print the info inside the function after passing it, it's exactly what I have in my JSON.

```
$.getJSON('/public/courseinfo.json', function(info){

        var x = some_function(courses, info);

    });
```

The error I get is "Cannot read property 'TUT' of undefined". Info is just the variable for the object I loaded from my JSON. When I print the variable to console, I get exactly how it should look like. If I just do `info[courses[i]] = some property' I don't get an error. 'info[courses[i]].length == 0' also prompts a cannot read property 'length' error. I'm not sure if it's a syntax issue, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: What's `courses[i]`?

Comment: courses[i] is the variable for the CourseName. For example, courses[0] in this case would be 'CourseName'. I just renamed the actual name to 'CourseName' (so for example Calculus) because it was more of course code in my case and changed it for privacy. I edited the JSON to make it more clear.

Comment: wouldnt you just want to use `info[i]`? assuming `courses[i]` is the data structure above, you are trying to get a subset of `info[i]` where the key is the JSON you are passing, rather than (what i can only assume) is you trying to access the name "Calculus 1", but it's getting the entire JSON object, not the key. If this is not the case, you will need to share a sample of `info` with us, because we can only make assumptions on what it looks like.

Comment: What's `info[]`?

Comment: info is the the object from the JSON file I have above. I did info[courses[i]] because info is a dictionary in this case (since that's what it is in the JSON), and I am trying to access the key courses[i]. courses[i] can be anything from 'Calculus 1' to 'Physics 1'. I only included 1 course for simplicity.

The 3rd bit of code I posted at the bottom, I pass info to some_function. The 2nd bit of code I posted is in some_function.

Comment: 1. info is empty/null/course is not existed; 2. course is empty/null; 3. `i` out of index. You can print out smaller step like `info`, `info[course[i]`, ... to trace.
`TUT` is inside `Calculus 1`. Are you sure `info[course[i]] = Calculus 1 {}`?

Comment: Yes I am sure. When I print info[courses[i]] to console, i get {'LEC":..., "TUT":..., "PRA":...}

Comment: @ManhLe it was an out of index error. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is throwing because `info[courses[i]]` is `undefined`. check whats returning as `courses[i]`.  `courses[i]` should be returning `Calculus 1`

Comment: courses[i] is returning the course as expected. info[courses[i]] is also not undefined when I don't have ['TUT'] after it. info[courses[i]] returns the value of the courses[i] key which are the dictionaries 'LEC', 'TUT', and 'PRA' as expected.

Comment: does your `info` object get modified before `if(info[courses[i]]['TUT']['sections'].length == 0){` here

Comment: It doesn't. However, I did seem to find a potential problem. I am able to access the property, but since it is in a loop, courses[i] may be going out of bounds and causing it to attempt getting the TUT property of an empty dictionary.

Comment: sweet. you can try this to `if(info[courses[i]] && info[courses[i]]['TUT']['sections'].length == 0){` get rid of undefined error

Comment: Yeah I added that in and it solves the problem. Of course its just a simple out of index error. Thanks!